# How to refuse a recipient in smtpd.SMTPServer.process_message?

Tags: python, email, smtp

Let's say your processing a message in an overridden class like:

```
class MailProcessorServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
  def process_message(self, peer, sender, rcpttos, data):
    badrecipients = []
    for rcpt in rcpttos:
      badrecipients.append(rcpt)

    #Here I want to warn the sender via a bounced email
    # that the recipient does not exist
    raise smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused(badrecipients)
    #but this just crashes the process and eventually the sender times out,
    # not good enough
```

I just want to bounce back to the sender immediately. Instead the sending service (say, GMail) just gives up eventually and warns the user many hours later.  The [documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/node620.html) seems pretty sparse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented only in [the sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/smtpd.py?revision=69846&view=markup) (sorry!), `process_message`'s specs include:

> This function should return None, for
>   a normal `250 Ok' response;  otherwise
>   it returns the desired response string
>   in RFC 821 format.

So you could "return '554 bad recipients %s' % badrecipients" instead of using that `raise` statement -- not entirely satisfactory (doesn't properly account for a mix of good and bad, which by RFC 821 *should* return a '250 Ok' but also send a warning mail later) but it does seem to be the "bounce back immediately" effect that you're looking for with that `raise`.

Answer (score 1):

The way to reject a message is to return a string with the error code from your `process_message` method; e.g.

```
return '550 No such user here'
```

However, RFC 821 doesn't allow error code 550 to be returned after the message data has been transfered (it should be returned after the `RCPT` command), and the smtpd module unfortunately doesn't provide an easy way to return an error code at that stage.  Furthermore, smtpd.py makes it difficult to subclass its classes by using auto-mangling "private" double-underscore attributes.

You may be able to use the following custom subclasses of smtpd classes, but I haven't tested this code:

```
class RecipientValidatingSMTPChannel(smtpd.SMTPChannel):
    def smtp_RCPT(self, arg):
        print >> smtpd.DEBUGSTREAM, '===> RCPT', arg
        if not self._SMTPChannel__mailfrom:
            self.push('503 Error: need MAIL command')
            return
        address = self._SMTPChannel__getaddr('TO:', arg)
        if not address:
            self.push('501 Syntax: RCPT TO: <address>')
            return
        if self._SMTPChannel__server.is_valid_recipient(address):
            self._SMTPChannel__rcpttos.append(address)
            print >> smtpd.DEBUGSTREAM, 'recips:', self._SMTPChannel__rcpttos
            self.push('250 Ok')
        else:
            self.push('550 No such user here')


class MailProcessorServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    def handle_accept(self):
        conn, addr = self.accept()
        print >> smtpd.DEBUGSTREAM, 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
        channel = RecipientValidatingSMTPChannel(self, conn, addr)

    def is_valid_recipient(self, address):
        # insert your own tests here, return True if it's valid
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will discard the mail without bouncing it.

```
return '554-5.7.1'
```

Problem: The sender MTA's will try to resend the mail again and again if you reject a mail without bouncing.

Error code `550` will bounce the email which can be a bad idea as you don't want to give a spamer any information concerning your mail server. Be careful with that.

```
return '550'
```

Both errors will raise an `smtplib.SMTPException`. Here is the simplified code I use to handle such exceptions.

```
try:
    if bounce:
        return '550 Bad address'
    else:
        self.send_and_quit(sender, recipients, data)
except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
    raise e
except Exception as e:
    # Catch any other exception
    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())

    if not isinstance(e, smtplib.SMTPException):
        self.send_and_quit(sender, recipients, data)
    else:
        raise e
```